# Работа над [ошибка]ми

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, метки, удаление-метки

Случайно наткнулся на метку [ошибка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0).

Там даже в описании:

> НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ ЭТУ МЕТКУ. Лучше напишите подробно, в чем ошибка.
>   Обязательно добавьте к вопросу полученное вами сообщение об ошибке.
>   Если ошибка вызвана кодом - приложите код.

Может лучше удалить вовсе эту метку? Ведь формально под эту метку можно подвести большую часть вопросов на SO, тогда она теряет всякий смысл.

Comment: Вижу, вы вчера неплохо подчистили метку. Я тоже принял посильное участие, да и другие участники. Сегодня уже 189 вопросов осталось.

Comment: @NickVolynkin надеюсь в ближайшее время покончить с этой меткой )

Comment: 160 осталось =)

Comment: заодно вычистил [tag:bug]

Comment: @NickVolynkin 140. Я по своим тегам закончил. Позже и по остальным пройдусь.

Comment: Кстати! В вопросах про удаление меток должны быть лулзы и игра слов. Срочно добавьте.

Comment: @NickVolynkin 100 (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, это описание для того и было поставлено, чтобы на новые вопросы эту метку не ставили, пока ее удаляют со старых.

Сложность в том, что нужно не просто удалять, а полностью перерабатывать каждый вопрос. Что-то редактировать, что-то закрывать. Как можно догадаться, вопросы с такой меткой часто нуждаются в улучшении.

Ещё одна проблема – кое-кто был против массового выпиливания меток и даже баном угрожал. Но теперь это почти в прошлом.

Полезная ссылка: [только вопросы с меткой [ошибка] и вашими избранными метками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=intags%3Amine%20[%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0]%20is%3Aq).

Comment: То есть вопрос только в том, что никто не хочет разгребать старые вопрос? Я бы мог этим заняться, но только по профильным вопросам, в которых разбираюсь.

Comment: @Suvitruf: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=intags%3Amine+[%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0]+is%3Aq

Comment: Как я погляжу, у многих вопросов вполне безболезненно можно убрать эту метку.